Spring gRPC @ExceptionHandler uses outdated Context generation
I'm using Spring Boot gRPC and encountered the problem that my set context (which I prepare in a @ServerInterceptor) is not used in exceptions at @GrpcAdvice ExceptionHandler. It handles Context.current() generation 5, while I intercept all incoming calls with a context of generation 6, in which I have prepared the user's metadata. The service methods also work with Context.current() with generation 6 and have access to the prepared metadata, but the exception handler does not.
How can I tell my ExceptionHandler to use the latest context generation (which should be 6 and not 5)?
I have already tried to get the latest version with a new Context.current() call in the ExceptionHandler, but it stays at generation 5.
Context.current().fork() has also created a new generation (gen 6), but its content does not match my context generation 6 from the interceptor at all.

I've just figured out that I can set my own Advice Order by using an @Order annotation. Putting @Order(0) above the server interceptor and @Order(1) above the exception handler leads to the wished behaviour, that the interceptor prepares the context now BEFORE it arrives in the exception handler :)
